# How to push a notification after specific time even the when the application is closed in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

i want to ask you : 
How to push a notification after specific time even when the application is closed?
like after 10 minutes, the application will push notification to the user.put it is not from the server so i can not use C2DM!

any code or tutorial or link will be helpful, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the AlarmManager to set an alarm which is fired after 10 minutes. Then react to the alram e.g. by sending the notification. Here is more information about the AlarmManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Look at AlarmManager example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example/8801990#8801990